# Slim 3 & Eloquent call more than 1 tables in single Model file

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

Recently I've been learning to use Slim 3 and eloquent.

What I'm trying to do is this (if it's even possible that is)

So I have a Model.php file

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

class Course extends Model{

    protected $table = "courses";

    public function GetCourses(){

    }


}

?>
```

And my Controller.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\Course;
use Slim\Views\Twig as View; 

class CourseController extends Controller{

    public function index($request,$response){

        return $this->view->render($response,'course/CourseNew.twig',$data);

    }

}
?>
```

So my question is inside the Model.php is it possible to call another table somehow?

I've already called mine with `protected $table = "courses";` I kind of understand that the table i defined is for the whole **Class** but is there a way or a workaround?

The main idea here is that i have some database tables that are very small and are not worth making another Model files for them

If this is not possible what is the alternative?

Do I have to make another Model file and call it on top of my controller where i need it use **namespace App\Models\"new_model";**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate the data structure from the data access logic. For example: put the code for the database queries into a Repository. A repository does not care where the data comes from (table x or table y).

#### Example

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Model\Course;

class CourseRepository extends Repository
{
    public function __construct(Connection $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findCourceById(int $courseId): ?Course
    {
        // execute query here
        //$this->db->....

        return $course;
    }

   public function findSomething(): array
    {
        // execute query here
        //$this->db->....

        return $rows ?: [];
    }
}
```